# Whole wheat pasta from milling to the results

Tags: pasta

Can it work to make pasta from freshly home-milled flour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I will show you. Here are my experiment results.

[image: Milling Bicycle]

I have this as my mill. It takes a long time to go from wheat to flour and I mean like hours maybe even days.

[image: Pasta dough with resting times and ratio]

I tried a 2 3/4 cup flour: 6 eggs: 5 tsp oil ratio and kneaded both batches for a good 10 minutes and rested 1 overnight and 1 for 30 minutes.

[image: before and after with the pasta roller]

I obviously got more than what is shown but I can't show a full 20 ounces with each strand separate.

[image: Pappardelle after cooking]

those black lines are supposed to be the pasta, the dark orange representing that it is whole wheat pasta. The brighter orange is the cheddar cheese sauce. I made this by taking some sharp and some mild cheddar that I have made myself and melting it on low bit by bit so that instead of a crust I would get a smooth sauce. It turned out good and after about 5-6 minutes, maybe less, maybe more, it was al dente and it didn't turn out to eggy or flourly or oily. I think I have found the right ratio for my whole wheat pasta.

Comment: I'm not certain the pictures add anything here.
Also they are not so great.
If you must use paint to make diagrams at least use the text tool for the text.
Better yet do diagrams in something that supports decent shapes etc, like inkscape.

Comment: caters, I think your answer is mostly fine. If you actually did all this work, posting an answer about it is exactly what we want. I won't undelete it for you - that's your decision - but don't let one user who doesn't like MSPaint stop you from posting. I do agree that the images might not add all that much, since you pretty much explained it all in the text, but it's up to you whether you want to include them. If you do, I might suggest trimming the extra white space off the sides so they don't take up so much space.

Comment: You're milling grain with a bicycle? Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can make pasta from freshly milled flour but depending on your grain mill the results might not be what you expect. Some grain mills like the [KitchenAid](http://www.kitchenaid.com/shop/countertop-appliances-1/countertop-appliances-2/stand-mixer-attachments-3/-%5BKGM%5D-400565/KGM/) will only grind as fine as corn meal and wheat bran that size could result in a very grainy pasta and might not work well for things like angel hair.

If you've already got a grain mill then go for it! You have nothing to lose and everything to gain by giving it a shot, just be sure to grind as fine as possible. If you're shopping for a grain mill ask the manufacturer if it will grind as fine as pastry flour or Italian Type 00.